# Error: cannot open display: :0.0 - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server

Tags: rhel, x11, firefox, display

I am trying to open up firefox in my Red Hat machine. I am doing,

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

and typing,

```
firefox
```

I am getting

```
Error: cannot open display: :0.0
```

Is there any way to know what packages are missing or needs to be installed or any log files I can refer to, to be able to load firefox from terminal.

Comment: Is xorg running on :0?

Comment: @IporSircer, how do I check if xorg is running on :0 ?

Comment: @agc, I am not sure if Xvfb is running in my system and if it is running what display number it is using. Is there a quick way to find this? I don't want to randomly paste commands from the internet into my machine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. I had to use X11 forwarding using Xming. Below link provides more details.

https://wiki.utdallas.edu/wiki/display/FAQ/X11+Forwarding+using+Xming+and+PuTTY